# After a hard restart, I am unable to repair the MBR of my BitLocked drive and don't have the key

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, mbr, hard-drive-recovery, password-recovery

Why would Microsoft not build in a password entry widget into the repair process?

How can I save my data? I've tried everything I can think of.

Windows 8.1 Pro (not sure if version N or not, not sure how to tell).

Tried boot repair, SFC. Tried plugging into another computer, tried plugging into SATA-to-USB. Can't get anything other than Windows Recovery Environment to recognize the drive's presence. It might only be a rote response to dead-ends.

Comment: If you've got BitLocker on and a TPM then the key is safe inside the TPM chip...If you can get to tools such as command prompt (from startup repair) and you can use, say, `diskpart` to see your C-drive or SFC then you've already got past BitLocker as the TPM chip has the key and Windows has unlocked the drive already, using it

Comment: No TPM, no recognition through command-line. "Device not ready".

Comment: You're running out of options if you haven't got the key...

Comment: Does anyone else have ideas?